# How to use Watir to wait until JavaScript loads and then scrape page with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir

I am trying to scrape a page from [Rotoworld](https://www.rotoworld.com/basketball/nba/player/30573/marvin-bagley) that has dynamically loaded content.
I'm trying to get the content that loads inside of the DIV with the `"player-content__wrapper"`  class.

I'm trying to use Watir to wait until the content loads, and then use Nokogiri to scrape that page after the content I want is there, but I am not sure how to do it:

```
def scrape
  browser = Watir::Browser.new
  browser.goto('https://www.rotoworld.com/basketball/nba/player/30573/marvin-bagley')
  js_doc = browser.element(css: ".player-content__wrapper").wait_until(&:present?)
  new_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(js_doc)
  browser.close
end
```

I'm trying to save the page with the content I want loaded into the `js_doc` variable, but I am getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for #Watir::HTMLElement:0x00007fda322b0a70
```

Comment: you want to pass in the inner_html, not the Watir Element itself; try: `js_doc.inner_html`

Comment: @titusfortner, thank you so much!!!!! That was it!! Last question, I am trying to set up this entire scraping function in my backend, so I don't want a new browser window to open everytime the function gets called, is it possible to do that?

Comment: See "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)" and "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)". SO isn't a message board, it's more like a reference book, and, as such, grammar, spelling, formatting and details, matter.